# Adding an image to QLabel with rounded borders

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

Is there a way to add background image to a QLabel programatically?

I would like to create a QLabel with rounded borders containing an image. I've tried setting the background image in the QLabel's stylesheet but it doesn't seem to work.

```
self.ui.thumbnail.setStyleSheet("background-image:url("+self.pathToThumbnail+");")
```

I've also tried using [QPixmap](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QPixmap.html?highlight=qpixmap#PySide.QtGui.QPixmap), however, it seems like the image just overlaps the Qlabel.